# Restart an Express.js server with the same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js app that uses Express.js to listen for connections. The code is something like so:

```
const express = require("express");
var server = express();
server.get("/test", (req, res) => testResponse(req, res));
server.listen(9001);
console.info("Server is listening to port 9001.");
```

I'd like to implement a way to restart the server without having to restart the whole app. However, I can't seem to properly shut down the server and free the port.
Here's what I tried:

```
server.close();
console.info("Server closed. Restarting.");

var server = express();
server.get("/test", (req, res) => testResponse(req, res));
server.listen(9001);
console.info("Server is listening to port 9001.");
```

As soon as I run this, I get

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::9001

What would be the correct way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[`server.close()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) is asynchronous and takes a callback.  Try waiting until the server is actually closed before starting a new one:

```
server.close(()=>{

    console.info("Server closed. Restarting.");

    var server = express();
    server.get("/test", (req, res) => testResponse(req, res));
    server.listen(9001);
    console.info("Server is listening to port 9001.");

});
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this brings another question: what if I want to separate this behavior into two functions? One function for closing the server, and one for starting it again?
A.k.a. closeServer() and startServer()

Comment: You are explaining `server.close()` for node server. for express app there is no method called close.

Answer (score 0):

As of Express 3, the `app.close()` method seems to have disappeared, which means Express users have no means of gracefully stopping an application. Express is really a listener to http request events which means you can do this:

```
const express = require("express");
var server = express();
server.get("/test", (req, res) => testResponse(req, res));
var app = server.listen(9001, function () {
    console.log('Listening :)');
    app.close(function () {
        console.info("Server closed. Restarting.");
        var server = express();
        server.get("/test", (req, res) => testResponse(req, res));
        server.listen(9001);
        console.info("Server is listening to port 9001.");
    });
});;
console.info("Server is listening to port 9001.");
```

For more on this you can refer [hardening nodejs for production](http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-3-zero-downtime-deployments-with-nginx)

Comment: are there any caveats of using this in production?

Comment: But [`app.listen()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) still returns a node `http.Server` instance.

Comment: Yes. That's how we can stop the server using `http.Server.close()` method

Comment: @AyushGupta, for production related you can refer [this](http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-3-zero-downtime-deployments-with-nginx)